# Error During building of a trial Ubuntu App using Cordova

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development

I am trying to develop html5 apps using cordova on my ubuntu desktop 15.10 for my phone which is running 15.04, following the configuration suggested [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/html-5/guides/cordova-guide/). 
However, on the build step in the above tutorial, i get this error:

```
sudo cordova build --device -- --framework ubuntu-sdk-15.04 --verbose
Running command: /home/arlee/myapp/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/build --device --framework ubuntu-sdk-15.04 --verbose
Building Phone Application...
Missing icon
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/arlee/myapp/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: 
/home/arlee/myapp/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/share/cordova-cli/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

I couldnt find any solution just by searching on google, so am posting this a question here.

Comment: Have you setup everything as mentioned in that link?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I followed the link step by step.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 has reached the end of its support life. Maybe try with the SDK of a supported release like 15.10 or 14.04. I don't even know if it's supposed to be possible to develop on one release of Ubuntu with the SDK of a different release.

Comment: It does work in some instances, I have built a very basic web app using the ubuntu sdk and been able to successfully run/deploy to the phone. The above command, does detect the phone and its architecture, but just gives an error, Missing Icon and terminates. I am quite sure the icon is there and referenced correctly from the config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to the above. It seems the cordova-ubuntu ppa is to blame, which comes with an earlier version of cordova(3.6 or something). I un-installed it and installed cordova via node.js/npm package. It installed a newest version of cordova (6.0.0) which works perfectly on 15.10 desktop and the 15.04-armhf on the phone.